# How can I create an overlay on a graph such that it shows seasons?

Tags: r, graph, fill

I have the graph below: [image: Time series showing self-reporting data on visitation to a park]

Using the following code:

```r
ggplot(data= mean_values, aes(x = Date, y = mean_B)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(
    x="Date", 
    y = "Mean", 
    title = "Time Series Analysis of respondents visiting a park in the last 12 months"
  ) + 
  geom_smooth(method= "lm", se = FALSE)
```

I want to add in coloured in sections to show when Spring, Summer, Autumn and Winter are so an individual can see when there are different seasons. Drawn crudely as seen:

Desired output of seasons:
[image: Desired output of seasons]

I tried first assigning seasons to a data frame and creating a start and end date:

```r
seasons <- data.frame(
  Season = c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter"),
  Start_Date = as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-09-01", 
                         "2020-12-01")),
  End_Date = as.Date(c("2020-05-31", "2020-08-31", "2020-11-30", 
                       "2021-02-28"))
)
```

Then tried to input this into the graph as a fill:

```r
ggplot(data = mean_values, aes(x = Date, y = mean_B)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(
    x = "Date", 
    y = "Mean", 
    title = 
 "Time Series Analysis of respondents visiting a park in the last 12 months") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = Start_Date, xmax = End_Date, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
        fill = Season),
    alpha = 0.3, color = NA
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "Spring" = "green",
      "Summer" = "yellow", 
      "Autumn" = "orange", 
      "Winter" = "blue")
  ) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes to the call to `geom_rect`. First, because you are using a new data set from the other layers, you need to explicitly provide the `data` argument. Second, you need to provide finite values for `ymin` and `ymax`

```
  geom_rect(
    data = seasons, # different data
    aes(
      xmin = Start_Date, 
      xmax = End_Date, 
      ymin = min(mean_values$mean_B), # match min from other data set
      ymax = max(mean_values$mean_B), # match max from other data set
      fill = Season
    ),
    alpha = 0.3
  )
```